# Download pop-up data of all points on a leaflet web map

Tags: web-scraping, leaflet

I am trying to get the pop-up data of all the points present in this interactive map made with leaflet. As far as I could observe, the pop-up data appears only when the point marker is clicked. The points are located in the element `<div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane">` and pop-ups in `<div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"></div>`

Is there any way to use some web scraping tools to click on all the points and download the pop-ups?

Webmap: http://gis.sutran.gob.pe/alerta_sutran/

Answer (score 0):

Open the Firefox [Network Monitor](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/index.html) and observe that a HTTP POST request is made to http://gis.sutran.gob.pe/alerta_sutran/script_cgm/carga_xlsx.php. To download, make use of [curl](https://curl.se/):

```
curl 'http://gis.sutran.gob.pe/alerta_sutran/script_cgm/carga_xlsx.php' -X POST --data-raw 'tipo=MAPA'
```

Comment: I have tried this but it did not work. I got the message "URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL"